# Compiling an IRtdServer Interface for Excel RTD() Function in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Is it possible to implement an IRtdServer interface for use by Excel in a .Net core project?

I have an existing .Net 4.6.1 framework project which I am looking to upgrade to .Net Core 3.  I am using Visual Studio 2019 Preview, version 3.0.100 preview9 of the .Net Core 3 SDK, and C#.

The heart of this project is a class to communicate with Excel using Excel’s RTD function:

```
[Guid("2B70D74D-A4F6-485F-8CDF-4CE514E75183")]
[ProgId("Ameritrade.RTD")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class RtdQuoteServer : IRtdServer
{
```

To create the interface for the.Net Framework project, I use the following:

%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe %~dp0\AmeritradeRtd\bin\Debug\AmeritradeRtd.dll /codebase

This works fine for the .Net framework version.  I have ported the application to .Net core, but have been unable to get it to work.

Running RegAsm against the .Net core dll generates the following error:

regasm: error RA0000 : could not load file or assembly System.Runtime, version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified.

I found this article, indicating that creating COM components is now supported in .Net Core 3.0 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com

I have attempted to register the DLL:

regsvr32 "C:\Projects\DEC Decision Capital\ARTHyperion\AmeritradeRtdCore\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\AmeritradeRtdCore.comhost.dll"

This gives three different results on three different PCs:

1)
[Regsvr32 error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBHWs.png)

2)
No error is displayed, but the registration doesn’t work.

3)
The registration succeeds, however the underlying issue remains, i.e. I can’t get Excel to communicate with it.

Comment: please elaborate on your motivation. It seems you are trying to do something esoteric, make COM based RTD server cross platform ಠ_ಠ ?

Comment: We have a .Net Core WPF front end application connected to a .Net Core library back end using AKKA.Net.  We want to connect our RTD project to the same .Net Core library back end using AKKA.Net.  We have tried replacing the .Net Core library back end with one based on the .Net Framework, however this stops the AKKA.Net serialisation from working (it doesn't seem to want to serialise between a .Net Core and a .Net Framework project).   We are not looking to make it cross platform.